# installation of apache2 + php82-fpm under macOS Ventura seems to keep php files in cache

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

A macports' installation of apache2 + php82-fpm under macOS Ventura seems to keep php files in cache, even before installing php82-opcache.

I don't know if this is coming from apache2 or php82-fpm, and I tried to set the cache-control in the header of my script like this without any success :

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

My production server is under linux and did not present this kind of problem at all.

When I empty the cache of the browser, the script executes correctly, whereas in the opposite case, not.

---

**Edit** : fixed this when I realized I had a not default value for `php_admin_value[session.save_path]`
I deleted this setting and everything when better.

Answer (score 0):

Opcode caching and http caching are very different things - only a *very* trivial analysis would confuse the two.

While your HTTP headers will prevent HTTP caching in most cases they're not correct.

You didn't say *why* you believed that data was being cached.

> fixed this when I realized I had a not default value for php_admin_value[session.save_path]

Next time check your webserver and PHP logs and what is being sent to your browser using the web developer tools.

Comment: I know now that both caching method are not the same, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I believed the data was being cached because even with a reset of some data in the mysql db, the behavior of the script did not change